# Real Time 'Validation' field in InfoPath that is fully functional in SharePoint currently!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

currently I have a calcuated field column in my SharePoint list that determines if a "QC Rep" labeled a record correctly. I use an IF/OR/AND statement in SharePoint that updates everytime a "QC Rep" picks a choice from different columns.

My question is, in my InfoPath form-- how do I get the same functionality? Functionality meaning, when someone is using the actual FORM from SharePoint, the validation field updates real-time before the form is submitted.

Here is my Sharepoint formula...

=IF(AND([QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]="N/A",[QC Complaint (Yes/No)]="N/A",[QC Complaint Risk Level]="N/A",[QC Non Complaint Reason]="N/A",[Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]="N/A",[Trigger Phrase Word(s)]="",[Trigger Phrase Score]=""),"New",

IF(AND([QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]="Yes",[QC Complaint (Yes/No)]="N/A",[QC Complaint Risk Level]="N/A",[Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]="N/A"),"Error",

IF(AND([QC Complaint (Yes/No)]="Yes",OR([QC Non Complaint Reason]<>"N/A",[QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]<>"Yes",[Trigger Phrase Word(s)]<>"",[Trigger Phrase Score]<>"",[Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]="N/A",[QC Complaint Risk Level]="N/A")),"Error",

IF(AND([QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]="N/A",OR([QC Non Complaint Reason]<>"N/A",[QC Complaint (Yes/No)]="N/A",[Trigger Phrase Word(s)]<>"",[Trigger Phrase Score]<>"",[Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]<>"N/A",[QC Complaint Risk Level]<>"N/A")),"Error",

IF(AND([QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]="Yes",[QC Complaint (Yes/No)]="No",OR([QC Non Complaint Reason]="N/A",[Trigger Phrase Word(s)]="",[Trigger Phrase Score]="",[Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]<>"N/A",[QC Complaint Risk Level]<>"N/A")),"Error",

IF(AND(LEFT([QC Valid Call (Yes/No)],2)="No",OR([QC Complaint (Yes/No)]<>"N/A",[QC Non Complaint Reason]<>"N/A",[QC Complaint Risk Level]<>"N/A",[Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]<>"N/A")),"Error","Valid"))))))

[image: SharePoint Validation Formula]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the validation instead of using a calculated column to validate the time when a new item or a modified item is saved to the list. It works whether you are using a OOB form or an InfoPath form.

Navigate to List settings -> validation settings, specify the formula you want to use to validate data when new items are saved to this list, and type the error message to help users understand what is needed for a valid list item. To pass validation, the formula must evaluate to `TRUE`. the formula is similar with the calculated formula.

[SharePoint Column Validation Examples](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/10/sharepoint-column-validation-examples.html)

[Examples of common formulas in SharePoint Lists](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

Another method using the infoPath form, you can use validation rules for field.

[Information about how to use validation rules in InfoPath form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-change-or-remove-data-validation-ac6b6477-8529-4e38-bdb8-2364e5a344c6)